# Where can I ask for a programming "idea", as I am stuck at somepoint in my project?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is it okay if I ask a question on Stack Overflow about the concern I have in my project? I am midway and unable to figure out how to move ahead.

I am not looking for someone to write and give code for me, but I am stuck at some point where I am unable to understand how to proceed, as it includes different programming languages/nosql database.

Or to put it in another way, where can I ask such question?